# What determines if a field of a CLR user-defined type is XML serializable?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, xml-serialization, sqlclr, user-defined-types

As one of my first .NET projects, I'm trying to create a CLR user-defined type for use in SQL Server.  In MSDN Library's [Requirements for Implementing UDTs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131082.aspx) it says:

> The UDT must implement System.Xml.Serialization.IXmlSerializable, or all public fields and properties must be of types that are XML serializable or decorated with the XmlIgnore attribute if overriding standard serialization is required.

What rule determines whether or not my fields and properties are XML serializable (using standard XML serialization)?  What types require custom XML serialization?

**Edit:** Ultimately, I want to know whether or not I have to implement the `IXmlSerializable` interface. It sounds like I have a choice to either implement it or limit myself to class/struct members that SQL Server CLR can handle automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Primitive .Net types like string, DateTime, int, boolean etc. are XmlSerializable, if the property of your custom type f.i. MyClass this type should be serializable, marked with [serilization attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83y7df3e%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: please forgive me: I don't understand what you've written.  Do you mean that members with non-primitive types are automatically XML serializable by SQL Server if and only if they are decorated with a particular attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Any type is considered XmlSerializable by default. You don't have to add anything special. You just need to follow some rules:

1. Your type must define a default constructor.
2. You must not use certain object, that can't be serialized to XML (like IDictionary derived objects.
3. If you have to place readonly properties, or properties of types that are not supported by XML serialization, you have to mark them with [XmlIgnore] attributes, so they will not be serialized.

If you want more control on the way your class is serialized (e.g. provide special names for nodes, control whether properties of your classes are serialized as nodes or attributes, etc), then you should look at these attributes http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83y7df3e.aspx

Comment: Can you expand on #3: Is it only `IDictionary`-derived objects that are not XML serializable?  

And regarding #4, MSDN's user-defined type examples show read-only properties without the `XmlIgnore` attribute (e.g. `IsNull` and `Null` in [this](http://msftengprodsamples.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/76846#22678) example).

Comment: I know exactly that Hashtable and Dictionary<> can`t be xml serialized like they are. Unfortunately I couldn`t find exact list of other types, that are not directly support. But, if you want, you create a custom type, that will implement IXmlSerializable. Then XmlSerialzer will use this implementation. So, in case you want to serialize Dictionary, you may create a custom implementation like this: `public class SerializableDictionary<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>, IXmlSerializable {/*Implement IXmlSerializable */}. About readonly fields, maybe I was wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

From "[Introducing XML Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182eeyhh.aspx)":

### Items That Can Be Serialized

The following items can be serialized using the XmLSerializer class:

- Public read/write properties and fields of public classes.
- Classes that implement ICollection or IEnumerable.

  Note:
  Only collections are serialized, not public properties.
- XmlElement objects.
- XmlNode objects.
- DataSet objects.